# access network share from windows mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

this question addresses the same problem I had with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195985.  This question focuses more on the specific problem I'm trying to solve.  Rather than change the original question, to what is essentially a different question, I'm starting this new one.

What I need to do is write a program for a device running Windows Mobile 6.5 that will copy files from a file share on a server to the mobile device.

I've been looking for hours for a way to access the network share from the mobile device, and I am yet to be successful.  Does anyone know of a way to access network shares from windows mobile 6.5, or can anyone confirm that that isn't supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve tryed to do that a few months ago, the only way was to implement the SMB protocol, what is not that simple... but you can run a web service on your machine, and downloard the files you want by HTTP or FTP.

Comment: Yeah, that Is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good post here on some registry settings that you need to change to allow the device to connect to SMB shares.  Also make sure that when you access the share, that your network card is set to "Work", and not "Internet" otherwise your DNS won't work for local LAN shares.

http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=27838

Comment: I've looked at that post, and it mostly involves changing some registry settings in windows Mobile.  I'm having some trouble accessing the registry editor.  Do you know if there is a built in registry editor, or whether i would have to download something?

Comment: This is a great tool, has a lot of good features and a registry editor  http://www.dotfred.net/TaskMgr.htm  . There is no built in editor that I know of.

Comment: I made the registry changes outlined in the OP of that topic, and I attempted to browse to my network share, and I get the following errors in sequence:  `The network path was not found`  and  `Network resource cannot be found or you do not have permission to access the network`.  The exact same errors I got before the changes.

Comment: If this is a matter of credentials, I know what credentials I would need to access the network share, I just don't know how I would enter them.

Answer (score 0):

(This is followup to Sam I am's comment on Mangist Answer as I lack necessary reputation to post a comment to an answer.)

To edit the registry on a Windows Mobile device I suggest trying [CeRegEditor](http://ceregeditor.mdsoft.pl/). It runs on your pc so you will need some method of docking your mobile device.